# How to re-enable FTP completion messages in Aptana Studio 3.0.7?

Tags: ftp, aptana

I was fiddling with Aptana Studio (3.0.7), which was probably my first mistake. Working with FTP, I turned off the pop-up message when a file finishes uploading that says something along the lines of "Transfer Completed! X Files Transferred X Directories Created". I would like to get this message to show up again, though I cannot find the option in the settings that allows me to do so...

Any help is appreciated! 
Thanks

Comment: Sorry for going off of the topic here, but as an additional issue, It seems I cannot upload new files via the Aptana FTP and I get the error message "Parent path doesn't exist." Any possible solutions to that one?

Answer (score 1):

@Daniel Otto
A bit late but better late than never :). The error message "Parent path doesn't exist" is due to your FTP user not having Write privileges on your server. If you're using a remote server contact your web hosting provider to get the privileges changed. If you've setup a localhost using XAMPP on Ubuntu 14.04, allow Write privileges to Owners and Groups by running this code in the Terminal:

> sudo chmod -R ug+w /var/www/html

/var/www/html denotes the default Ubuntu 14.04 root directory, yours may be different.